# Swift grammar: what the usage of [CGFloat: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()?

Tags: swift

I am reading some code from a open source project which is using swift. Here I come across the code `[CGFloat: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()`, and I don't understand the usage of the code and I even don't know how to google it.(what's the key word?)

My question is focus on the `[CGFloat: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()`, what the usage or how to understand it?

And below is the code in context.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    var rowCollections = [CGFloat: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()

    ...... // not concerned with the question
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Dictionary whose keys are of type `CGFloat` and whose values are of type `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]` (also known as `Array<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!